# why does xmllint return this as invalid

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xmllint, amazon-marketplace

When I try to validate an Amazon Marketplace Web Service SubmitFeed for order fulfillment I get the following error:

> xmllint.exe --schema OrderFulfillment.xsd OrderFulfillment.xml
>
> OrderFulfillment.xml:2: element AmazonEnvelope: Schemas validity error : Element
> 'AmazonEnvelope': No matching global declaration available for the validation r
> oot.
> OrderFulfillment.xml fails to validate

OrderFulfillment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>AXGZ4X5NTV6SN</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OrderFulfillment>
            <AmazonOrderID>104-5894782-1841713</AmazonOrderID>
            <FulfillmentDate>2012-04-07T15:54:40.154Z</FulfillmentDate>
            <FulfillmentData>
                <CarrierCode>USPS</CarrierCode>
                <ShippingMethod>Priority</ShippingMethod>
                <ShipperTrackingNumber>9109901000372243321450</ShipperTrackingNumber>
            </FulfillmentData>
        </OrderFulfillment>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, you have to validate with the parent schema, in this case amzn-envelope.xsd

See [How can lxml validate some XML against both an XSD file while also loading an inline schema too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424457/how-can-lxml-validate-some-xml-against-both-an-xsd-file-while-also-loading-an-in)